# Can an ORM be use for a system where the access is thru methods that returns DataTables?

Tags: .net, orm, architecture

We have a system (third party) where we access a web service to read data from its underlying database that returns .Net DataTable objects and in some cases even DataSet.

The system sometimes (depends on the web method) accepts the modified DataTable/DataSet to update/insert/delete data.

Other times, some web methods only have parameters for update/insert/delete (they call a store procedure behind the scene).

I'm trying to decouple this web service from our application and I was thinking that maybe an ORM would be one possible solution.

However, for what I could read on the internet it seems that the ORM **needs** direct access to the database which we don't have.

So, is there an ORM that could fit this scenario?

Comment: have you consider entity framework + POCO or entity framework + self tracking ?

Comment: It is my understanding that EF needs a database connection as well. Right?

Comment: Yes it does, but you are trying to decouple what tiers exactly? Your web service could interact with a Data Access Layer which can use any data access technology be it EF, ADO.net, etc ... might be that I don't understand your intent.

Comment: with EF + POCO (Persistence Ignorance, so no persistance infrastructure = no direct connection to you DB), you use your POCO object to transfert to your client and have a business layer to manipulate your poco object. And you would use the Data Access layer to persist the POCO object into the DB using EF.

Comment: I'm trying to decouple the client from the 3rd party web service and I'm exploring ideas about using an ORM (which may not be feasible).

Comment: What is the reason behind decoupling the web services from your application? If you are thinking of using an ORM, have you given a thought about the hardware infrastructure (like firewall etc., the very reason why the web service could exist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to decouple it is to:

- Create Data Transfer Objects (DTO'S)
- Use DTO's in all your services
- The first level of your service should be a facade that maps the DTO's to whatever objects you use in your data access technology

Comment: So, using DTO is there a way to use an ORM? The reason I'm evaluating an ORM solution is because it provides a lot of functionality (caching, lazy loading, transactions).